# Unable to connect to MySQL DB with powershell cmdlet

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am unable to connect to my MySQL DB with the MySQLcmdlets for powershell

```
Connect-MySqlServer -Server "127.0.0.1" -Database "pcinventory" -UserName "root" -Password $pass
```

Error message:

```
Connect-MySqlServer : Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MySqlServer -Server "127.0.0.1" -Database "pcinventory" -User ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:MySqlConnection) [Connect-M
   ySqlServer], MySqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlConnectionException,it.wiechecki.ps.mysql.ConnectMySQL
```

This worked perfectly in the past. I changed the server defaults for the DB from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4 already but no success.

Comment: It looks like you use a licensed software product, [MySQLCmdlets](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mysql/powershell/). Have you asked the publisher's tech support krewe for help? Have you tried specifying the connection character set explicitly? Try `Get-Help -Name Connect-MySqlServer` to find out how to do that.

Comment: There is an option -DefaultCharacterSet what value do you suggest me to use? -DefaultCharacterSet utf8mb4?